# Implicit Operator Conversion and Generics

Tags: c#, generics

Why does this conversion not work?

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
}

public interface IMyInterface2 : IMyInterface
{
}

public class MyContainer<T> where T : IMyInterface
{
     public T MyImpl {get; private set;}
     public MyContainer()
     {
          MyImpl = Create<T>();
     }
     public static implicit T (MyContainer<T> myContainer)
     {
        return myContainer.MyImpl;
     }
}
```

When I use my class it causes a compile time error:

```
IMyInterface2 myImpl = new MyContainer<IMyInterface2>();
```

Cannot convert from MyContainer`<IMyInterface2`> to IMyInterface2...hmmmm

Comment: I ran into this same problem. It's not a bug in the compiler, but rather, a documented part of the spec. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208796/c-compiler-bug-why-doesnt-this-implicit-user-defined-conversion-compile

A respected member of the C# compiler team added an answer to the above question and added, "this is a very, very confusing part of the spec".

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. That's helpful. I didn't think it was a bug but possibly something I didn't understand about the spec, which it turned out to be. Kind of sucks because it would have made my code much cleaner...oh well. I guess I'll just write my own language :P

Comment: I hear you. I have some structs like NonNull<T> and Maybe<T>, and converting to/from these types would be much cleaner had the spec allowed for this scenario. I wish they'd change the spec; I'd rather have the possibility of less-inexpensive conversions and enable this implicit conversion scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot define an implicit conversion to an interface. Therefore your generic implicit operation is not going to be valid for interfaces. See [blackwasp.co.uk](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpConversionOverload.aspx)

> You may not create operators that convert a class to a defined interface. If conversion to an interface is required, the class must implement the interface.

You may just have to end up writing the following, without *implicit magic*:

```
IMyInterface2 myImpl = new MyContainer<IMyInterface2>().MyImpl;
```

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with the fact that IMyInterface2 is an interface, if you replace it with

```
public class MyClass2 : IMyInterface
{
}
```

it does work.

Here is the reference,  [10.9.3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664464%28VS.71%29.aspx)