# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.BadRequestObjectResult'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I have an asp.net core 2.1 project and I'm getting the following error in my controller action:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.BadRequestObjectResult' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

This is my code:

```
[HttpPost("create")]
[ProducesResponseType(201, Type = typeof(Todo))]
[ProducesResponseType(400)]
public async Task<IList<Todo>> Create([FromBody]TodoCreateViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);   // This is the line that causes the intellisense error
    }

    await _todoRepository.AddTodo(model);
    return await GetActiveTodosForUser();
}


[HttpGet("GetActiveTodosForUser")]
[ProducesResponseType(200)]
[ProducesResponseType(404)]
public async Task<IList<Todo>> GetActiveTodosForUser(string UserId = "")
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserId))
    {
        UserId = HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Sid);
    }
    return await _todoRepository.GetAll(UserId, false);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your function is written to return Task<IList<Todo>> and  BadRequest(ModelState) obviously inst't of that type

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your action return type does not take in mind possible `BadRequest`.

Instead of direct usage of `IList<Todo>` you need to wrap it with generic `ActionResult` type.

`public async Task<ActionResult<IList<Todo>>> Create(...`

Here are the [related docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Answer (score 14):

For ASP.NET Core 2.1, you should use `ActionResult<T>` but there is a **limitation** with `Interface`'s.

**This Works**

```cs
public ActionResult<IList<string>> Create()
{  
    return new List<string> { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

**Doesn't Work**

```cs
public ActionResult<IList<string>> Create()
{
    //DOESN'T COMPILE:
    //Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type
    //'System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>' 
    //to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>>'
    //the cast here is for demo purposes.
    //the problem will usually arise from a dependency that returns
    //an interface.
    var result = new List<string> { "value1", "value2" }
                     as IList<string>;
    return result;
}
```

> C# doesn't support implicit cast operators on interfaces.
>   Consequently, conversion of the interface to a concrete type is
>   necessary to use ActionResult.

Source: [ActionResult type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.1#actionresultt-type)

---

- [Demo project](https://github.com/spottedmahn/Experiments/blob/12183df350219ddfa93bebeaa7495c2af69a30e3/SO%2051816947%20ActionResult%20Interfaces/SO%2051816947%20ActionResult%20Interfaces/Controllers/ValuesController.cs#L12)
- Interesting read on [C# doesn't support implicit cast operators on interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9231325/185123)

---

**Sidenote:** you don't need `[FromBody]` as ASP.NET will do that automatically.  [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50468541/185123).

Answer (score 9):

Actually you need to return **IActionResult** instead of **IList** for 
below ASP.NET Core 2.1,

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody]TodoCreateViewModel model)
```

Then it will work.

And for ASP.NET Core 2.1 as suggested by @amankkg,

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IList<Todo>>> Create([FromBody]TodoCreateViewModel model)
```

Comment: There is a [generic `ActionResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.1) in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Comment: I want to create the ToDo then return the list of all the ToDos for the user which is why I'm returning a List

Comment: can't use `interface`'s w/ `ActionResult`.  [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026659/185123)

Comment: @spottedmahn I'm using Interfaces with ActionResult, then how you can say that it doesn't work.
ActionResult<IEnumerable<PartViewModel>> Get(),
Working example is here: https://devniggaspk.azurewebsites.net/admin/api/course/1/Clips/course-parts

Comment: Weird, it didn't work for me and [the documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.1#actionresultt-type) it doesn't work either.

Comment: I have given you a working example, and in documentation 2nd part says the work-around is to return ToList(). One option to fix the preceding code is to return _repository.GetProducts().ToList(); Then how come it is weird?

Comment: Hi @Wiqi - it's weird because I was having trouble when trying to return interfaces.  I've since done some more research and learning .  I've also updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026659/185123) to reflect my new knowledge .