# Implicit Reference Conversion from reference type to interface for user defined types

Tags: c#

From C# 4.0 Spec section 6.1.6:

> The implicit reference conversions are:
>
> [...]
>
> From any reference-type to an interface or delegate type T if it has
>   an implicit identity or reference conversion to an interface or
>   delegate type T0 and T0 is varience-convertible (13.1.3.2) to T.

Vladimir Reshetnikov tells us that there is an implicit reference conversion from `List<string>` to `IEnumerable<object>`.  But, how can I apply this to a user defined type (is it even possible)?

I tried an implicit operator, custom derived types and a few varitions there-of...but I cannot reproduce the scenerio.  I have:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<object> specialClassConversion = new List<string>();
        IEnumerable<A> userdefinedTypeConversion = new List<B>();
        A implicitConversion = new B();//varience-convertible
        IC<A> explicitConversion = (IC<A>)new D<B>();//OK, varience-convertible
        IC<A> implicitConversion2 = new D<B>();//does not compile
    }
}

class A { }

class B : A { }

interface IC<T> { }    

class D<T> 
{
    //public static implicit operator IC(D<T> m)//Error: user-defined conversions to or from an interface are not allowed
    //{
    //    return null;
    //}
}
```

Comment: "implicit conversion" in the excerpt you quote doesn't mean "an implicit conversion operator exists", it just means "a conversion that doesn't need an explicit cast"

Comment: `IC<A> explicitConversion = (IC<A>)new D<B>();` isn't okay either, the cast should fail at runtime. Not without the interface being declared as either `interface IC<in T>` or `interface<out T>`. (I don't remember exactly which is which and what that means for subtype relationships between generic instantiations.) If they *were* variance-convertible, the line after that would compile.

Comment: @millimoose Actually `"an implicit conversion operator exists"` is *exactly* what it means.  Note that language provides an implicit conversion from a type to all of its base types as well as to any interfaces it implements, so it's not just user or language defined conversion operators.

Comment: @Servy Under *operator* I meant specifically the special methods C# lets you implement - I don't think of the language provided conversions as "operators". I guess I should have phrased that comment better. A better version would've been: "implicit conversion" doesn't *only* mean that you've defined an implicit conversion operator method, but *any* conversion that doesn't require an explicit cast (user-defined or language-defined.)

Comment: Well, `List<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` are both a user-defined types, so it must be possible somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a user-defined class or struct to be implicitly convertible to an interface, let your class/struct implement that interface.

**(Edit)**

And if you want `IC<B>` to be implicitly convertible to `IC<A>`, make the `IC<T>` interface *covariant* in `T` by specifying the `out` keyword, `interface IC<out T> { }`. The quote from the spec you gave tells that the "composition" of these two implicit conversion is also an implicit conversion.

**Source:**

```
interface IC<out T> {  }

class D<T> : IC<T>  { }
```

**(End edit)**

Regarding the `List<string>` class, it implements `IEnumerable<string>` which in turn is convertible (implicitly) to `IEnumerable<object>` because `IEnumerable<out T>` is *covariant* (`out`) in `T`.

(One reason why they didn't allow you to make a `public static implicit operator` which converts to/from the interface, is that somone could write a derived class which inherited from your class *and* implemented the interface. That would give a "natural" conversion between their class and the interface, but the `public static implicit operator` would also apply, leading to *two* conversions (one "natural" and one "user-defined") between the types, which would be confusing and ambiguous.)

Comment: Can you demostrate how this works with the code in the OP?  I tried implementing the interface and ran into various other implementation problems...one is noted in the comments in the OP.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey If you mean to make your interface covariant like `IEnumerable<>`, write `interface IC<out T> { }` (note the **`out`**). Be sure to have `D` implement the interface: `class D<T> : IC<T> { }` The "variance-convertible" stuff of the quote from the spec, is about covariance and contravariance, and in your code sample, use covariance.

Comment: The only way to make a conversion that involves an interface type is to make a conversion in class `C<T>` from `C<T>` to `T`, and then construct `C<IFoo>`. The code to deal with that situation in the compiler get my vote for the most arcane and difficult code in the compiler, and the specification is very difficult to read. Getting Roslyn to match some semblance of both the specification and the previous compiler was one of the toughest challenges in the Roslyn semantic analysis effort.

Comment: @EricLippert I tried it out with the Visual C# 5.0 compiler. It looks like in that case the conversion to `IFoo` is never considered. In the "Related" column on the right I found this question about it: [C# compiler bug? Why doesn't this implicit user-defined conversion compile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208796/)

Comment: @EricLippert 's post helped me understand a subtle covarient issue that I missed in this case: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/30/what-s-the-difference-between-covariance-and-assignment-compatibility.aspx