# How can I cast a List into a type which inherits from List<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, casting

I have two classes:

```
public class Row : Dictionary<string,string> {}
public class Table : List<Row> {}
```

In a method which should returns an object of type **Table**, I try to filter an object of type **Table** with the **Where**-Statement and return this object after filtering.

```
Table table = new Table();
table = tableObject.Where(x => x.Value.Equals("")).ToList();
return table;
```

My problem is the cast of the resulting IEnumerable.

1. Conversion with **(Table)** throws an InvalidCastException

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Row]' to type 'Table'.

2. Conversion with **as Table** results in an null object

How can I return an object of type **Table** out of an IEnumerable?

Comment: Are you trying to get list of Tables or List of Rows inside one Table? what type is "tableObject" ?

Comment: Do you want to get all tables where at least one row has the value you're cheking in 'Equals'?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22402329/implicit-cast-from-ienumerablet-to-mycollection

Comment: So `tableObject` is not a `List<Table>` but a `List<Row>`?

Comment: A `List<Row>` won't work either because a Row does not have a `Value`.

Comment: Are you sure that inheriting from `List<Row>` is a good idea here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make an extension method to do this job:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static Table ToTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection) where T: Row
    {
        Table table = new Table();
        table.AddRange(collection);
        return table;
    }
}
```

Now you can simply call this method:

```
table = tableObject.Where(x => x.Value.Equals("")).ToTable();
```

Or you can do it directly, since you create an empty `Table`:

```
Table table = new Table();
table.AddRange(tableObject.Where(x => x.Value.Equals("")));
return table;
```

Comment: @D.Weder you are welcome. But do you have any other properties in `Table` ? because in this solution they will get default values!

Answer (score 3):

I assume your `tableObject` is a `List<Row>`. Every `Table` is a `List<Row>` but not every `List<Row>` is a `Table`, that's why casting doesn't work.

It sounds like providing a constructor would be an obvious solution:

```
public class Table : List<Row>
{
    public Table(IEnumerable<Row> rows) : base(rows) {}
}
```

---

```
table = new Table(tableObject.Where(x => x.Value.Equals("")));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```
public class Row{
    //whatever you have inside it
    public string MyValue{get;set;}
}

public class Table{
    public List<Row> Rows{get;set;}
}

Table table = new Table();
//renaming tableObject to bigListOfRows
table.Rows = bigListOfRows.Where(x => x.MyValue.Equals("")).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Table table = new Table();
```

is not list so instead, you should do is something like:

```
var tables = new List<Table>();
var tableObject = new List<Table>{};
tables = tableObject.ToList();
```

Comment: You calling ToList() on List and assigning it to another list...it could be shorter like tables = tableObject. But I think he means something other in his question.