# Cannot implicitly convert in async method

Tags: c#, .net, implicit-conversion

The following code doesn't compile, and I fail to understand why

```
namespace ImplicitConversion
{
    struct Wrapper<T>
    {
        public static implicit operator Wrapper<T> (T input)
        {
            return new Wrapper<T> ();
        }
    }

    interface IFoo
    {
    }

    class Foo:IFoo
    {
    }

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {       
        }

        static Wrapper<IFoo> Test ()
        {
            IFoo foo = new Foo ();
            return foo; // Cannot implicitly convert type 'ImplicitConversion.IFoo' to 'ImplicitConversion.Wrapper<ImplicitConversion.IFoo>' (CS0029) (ImplicitConversion)
        }
    }
}
```

Why can't I use the implicit conversion?

Comment: this doesn't really have anything to do with it being an async method btw. this conversion fails whether it's a `Task<Wrapper<IFoo>>` or just a `Wrapper<IFoo>`

Comment: Also, it seems that serdar is right, you cannot implicitly convert from interfaces: http://stackoverflow.com/a/143567/526704

Comment: @DLeh you're right. I've edited the question

Comment: Was also going to wield the dupehammer, but to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208796/c-sharp-compiler-bug-why-doesnt-this-implicit-user-defined-conversion-compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As DLeh mentioned it is not about async.

AFAIK interfaces can not be converted(either implicit or explicit).

See this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/143567/526704

Comment: Yup, 6.4.4 in the C# spec. (Also if you remove the generics, you get an explicit 'User-defined conversion from interface' error.)

Comment: I've modified the question