# Cannot implicitly convert IQueryable<T> to a custom type, but other types work

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

My application's business-logic layer performs its own authorization checks and all data-querying operations return a `GuardedResult<TResult>` value, here's the definition:

```
public class GuardedResult<TResult> {
    public TResult Result { get; }
    public Status Status { get; }
    public GuardedResult(TResult result, Status status) {
        this.Result = result;
        this.Status = status;
    }
    public static implicit operator GuardedResult<TResult>(TResult result) {
        return new GuardedResult<TResult>(result, Status.Success);
    }
}
```

Used like so:

```
public partial class EmployeesBusinessLogic {

    public GuardedResult<Employee> GetEmployee(Int64 employeeId) {

        if( this.CurrentUser.CanReadAll ) {

            return this.Data.Employees.GetEmployeeById( employeeId );

        }
        else if( this.CurrentUser.CanReadSelf ) {

            if( this.CurrentUser.EmployeeId == employeeId ) {

                return this.Data.Employees.GetEmployeeById( employeeId );
            }
            else {

                return new GuardedResult<Employee>( null, Status.AccessDenied );
            }
        }
        else {
            return new GuardedResult<Employee>( null, Status.AccessDenied );
        }
    }
}
```

This builds and works fine.

However when I change `TResult` to a closed-generic `IQueryable` it fails:

```
public GuardedResult<IQueryable<Employee>> GetEmployees() {

    if( this.CurrentUser.CanReadAll ) {

        return this.Data.Employees.GetAllEmployees();
    }
    else {

        return new GuardedResult<IQueryable<Employee>>( null, Status.AccessDenied );
    }
}
```

The compiler error is:

> Error CS0266
>   Cannot implicitly convert type '`System.Linq.IQueryable<Initech.Employee>`' to '`Initech.GuardedResult<System.Linq.IQueryable<Initech.Employee>>`'.
>    An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Here is the the relevant definitions from the `EmployeesData` class:

```
public IQueryable<Employee> GetAllEmployees() {
    return this.dbContext.Employees;
}

public Employee GetEmployeeById(Int64 employeeId) {
    return this.dbContext.Employees.SingleOrDefault( e => e.EmployeeId == employeeId );
}
```

Comment: `return this.Data.Employees.GetAllEmployees();` I believe this is the line which causes the problem

Comment: What does `GetAllEmployees` return? It's not used in the "code that works"?

Comment: @orhor I have amended my posting with the definition of the 'GetAllEmployees` method.

Comment: @jcl it returns an `IQueryable<Employee>`, the same type as declared in the business layer. I have amended my posting with the details.

Comment: @Dai, You need to return `GuardedResult<IQuerable<Employee>>` and not `IQuerable<Employee>`, e.g. `return new GuardedResult<IQueryable<Employee>>( this.Data.Employees.GetAllEmployees(), Status.AccessDenied );`

Comment: @Dai, yeah, I could have guessed if I had read the question better... tough luck, implicit casting won't work for you... check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208796/c-sharp-compiler-bug-why-doesnt-this-implicit-user-defined-conversion-compile) specifically the accepted answer and the one below by Eric Lippert

Comment: @ChrisWohlert he obviously wanted the implicit casting operator to work :-)

Comment: @Jcl, Oh yeah, sorry, might've been too quick there. :)

Comment: as I stated, your `GetEmployees()` returns `GuardedResult<IQueryable<Employee>>`, but `GetAllEmployees()` returns `IQueryable<Employee>`. This is something that needs to be corrected. You have this line: `return this.Data.Employees.GetAllEmployees();` which is most probably uncompileable.

Comment: @orhor Please read my question fully. I'm trying to make use of C#'s `implicit` type conversion capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I'm not answering what you want here, but [as it turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208796/c-sharp-compiler-bug-why-doesnt-this-implicit-user-defined-conversion-compile), the implicit casting operator won't work in your case (and although confusingly, the why is in the specs, but don't let me try to make sense of it, and see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1209560/68972) for why)

Then again, for your specific case, it'd be a matter of doing:

```
return new GuardedResult<IQueryable<Employee>>(
          this.Data.Employees.GetAllEmployees(), Status.Success);
```

Again, more likely not what you wanted to hear

Comment: At least I can save on typing by wrapping the constructor call in an abbreviated function.